In postgres, how know which query is slow for each schema
I use postgres schemas for a multi-tenant setup:
public
company_a
company_b

I need to see which queries x company are slow, is possible to do this directly with postgres?
P.D: Also, to see which values cause the slowdown, I only see parameters there:
SELECT
round(total_exec_time::numeric, 2) AS total_time,
calls,
round(mean_exec_time::numeric, 2) AS mean,
round((100 * total_exec_time /
sum(total_exec_time::numeric) OVER ())::numeric, 2) AS percentage_cpu,
query
FROM    pg_stat_statements
ORDER BY total_exec_time DESC
LIMIT 5;

-- query only show
UPDATE customer_sync SET customer_code = $1, address_co


I don't think that there is a way to get that information.

In clear ISO Standard SQL, not in the abstruse PG dialect, you can find the user that runs the query which has been associated tho the SQL schema with :
SELECT CAST(total_exec_time AS numeric(16,2)) AS total_time,
       calls,
       CAST(mean_exec_time AS numeric (16,2)) AS mean,
       CAST(100.0 * total_exec_time / sum(total_exec_time) OVER () AS numeric(24,2) AS percentage_cpu,
       query,
       rolname
FROM   pg_stat_statements AS q
       INNER JOIN pg_authid AS a
          ON q.userid = a.oid
ORDER  BY total_exec_time DESC FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;

